# How upload my website on different servers at the same time?

Tags: web, ftp, mirroring, filezilla

I want to create mirrors for my website and I want to know if there is a way to upload my website on different servers at the same time ( through filezilla, wget or other tools ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

[Mirroring with rsych](http://www.howtoforge.com/mirroring_with_rsync)

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy code you need to make sure that your code changes land on all your servers, one way to do this would be to use a tool like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) if you're inclined to ruby or [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.3/) or [Puppet](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Python_Version_Patterns) if you prefer python.

The other way is to deploy onto one server and periodically mirror them over to the other servers [using rsync as Paul suggested](http://www.howtoforge.com/mirroring_with_rsync)